# How to Use This StackPanel as a Resource

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am just trying to get the StackPanel content into a ResourceDictionary. I tried wrapping it into a data tempplate but no go. Some other sort of template? A style?

How can I extract this to a resource and then use the content in my view's grid layout?

Cheers,
Berryl

## the xaml to move

```
<StackPanel x:Name="_filterByTypeOptions" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5, 5" >
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelRadioButtonStyle}" 
         IsChecked="{Binding ShowAllContacts, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         Content="{resx:Resx Filter_ByType_ShowAll}" ToolTip="{Resx Filter_ByType_ShowAll_ToolTip}"
         />
    // ... more of the same

</StackPanel>
```

## UPDATE

## current template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FilterTypeByTemplateControl">
    <StackPanel x:Name="_filterByTypeOptions" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5, 5" >
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelRadioButtonStyle}" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding ShowAllContacts, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     Content="{resx:Resx Filter_ByType_ShowAll}" ToolTip="{Resx Filter_ByType_ShowAll_ToolTip}"
                     />
        /// etc.
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

## used in another StackPanel of the view

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="_filterByNameOptions" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5, 5" >
            // ... more stuff

            <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource FilterTypeByTemplateControl}"/>

        </StackPanel>
```

[image]

## finally!

This works

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FilterTypeByTemplateControl}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use data templates?

Comment: @WallstreetProgrammer. I was getting an error before, probably because the project needed a build. But now I am doing something else silly - see from my updated post that instead of the stack panel displaying I am getting it's ToString(). I need to beef up my templating skills!

Comment: @WallstreetProgrammer. Ok I got something working as per last edit in post. Let me know if there is something I can do better, preferably as an answer so I can close this and leave a bread crumb forr someone else with DataTemplate learning issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ContentControl 
      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FilterTypeByTemplateControl}" />
```

Comment: This will lose the bindings inside the resource (ShowAllContacts in this example). It needs to be: <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FilterTypeByTemplateControl}"/>